# Apache Trying to Bind to 0.0.0.0:443

Tags: networking, apache-http-server

I am trying to set up Apache on Windows 8.1 Pro x64. The version of Apache that I have installed is Apache 2.4.10 x64 from [Apache Haus](http://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx?dli=QUVhnejVUQw8EVRtGZXFjQKVlUGR1UwZzYHRnM). The problem that I am having with Apache is that every time I try starting it, here's what happens.

[image: Apache Server Start Error]

I do not know why I am having an issue with Apache trying to bind to 0.0.0.0:443 because nowhere in the configuration file have I told Apache to do this. I want to use Apache only on my `localhost` as a testing server. I currently have IIS installed and it is running on the default port `80` so I want to configure Apache to run on port `8080`. [Here](http://pastebin.com/W5YWeF20) is a copy of my Apache configuration file. What's causing Apache to try binding to an address that I clearly do not have defined?

Comment: 443 is the https port, are you sure that you don't have any SSL config included? Apache installs tend to have a modular configuration - check to see if you Include something that has SSL.

Comment: @RichHomolka Are you referring to [this](http://pastebin.com/wJqBLZu3)?

Comment: yep.  Check to see if that is Included (either directly, or in a glob, you can do Include /dir/*.conf) in your current config.

Comment: Also check to make sure you're not running such software as Skype as this listens using 80 and 443...

Comment: @BigChris That could be my problem then! Not only do I use IIS, but I also use Skype.

Comment: Close Skype, reconfigure IIS ports and see what happens... Alternatively reconfigure Apache to listen to, say, 8080 and 10443...? It's your call :)

Comment: @RichHomolka Thank you for your help. I was able to resolve the issue by disabling the `Use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connections` option on Skype under `Tools > Options... > Advanced > Connection`. After doing this, I was able to start Apache without changing any SSL stuff.

Comment: @BigChris Thank you for your help. I was able to resolve the issue by disabling the `Use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connections` option on Skype under `Tools > Options... > Advanced > Connection`. After doing this, I was able to start Apache without changing any SSL stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since neither of the two users who helped me wrote an answer and instead commented, I was able to resolve the issue by disabling the `Use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connections` option on Skype under `Tools > Options... > Advanced > Connection`. After doing this, I was able to start Apache without changing any SSL stuff.